# Confirm box function undefined

Tags: javascript, validation, confirm

Just wanted to ask a quick question. shown in the code below that I've done, I was wondering if you could tell me why on IE console that it says the function name is undefined.

JavaScript Code:

```
function check() {
var checked = null;
var inputs = document.getElementsByName('examGroup');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
if (inputs[i].checked) {
checked = inputs[i];
break;
}
}
```

Thanks everyone, and hope you can help!
----EDIT----

Here is the IE console error with the line number:
SCRIPT5009: 'check()' is undefined - File: Index.html, Line: 160, Column: 27

Here is where it is getting stuck at:

```
<input onClick="check()" type="radio" id="A1" name="examGroup" value="GCSE" />GCSE
```

Comment: Where is the javascript?  Within the HTML, or in an external file?  And if that is the actual indentation of your code, you're making life difficult for yourself by not being able to see the individual blocks of code

Comment: the JavaScript is on the name form but in a separate script. How could I structure it then?

Comment: Can you show the exact error, and what line is throwing it?  [It appears](http://jsfiddle.net/sa0amrcv/) to run without errors.

Comment: where are you declaring/importing the js script?

Comment: I have made the changes and have shown the changes.

Comment: I'm importing the code at the top where the script begins in the head.

Comment: Could you ple add the code along with the head and script tags? Also I can't see the matching  </p> tag, and no need to add a semicolon after the function call onClick="check()".

Comment: If you probably added the script in the head it should work fine. Show us how you added the script, is the script loading (check the console)?

Comment: I've have just added all the code to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `check()` is defined within the function `validateForm()` and in such is not really defined by itself. Move it outside the function `validateForm()` along with the rest of your functions.

```
function validateForm() {
    ...
};

function check() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: hello there, the only problem that I have with this is, it works however I have come across the fact that it ignores the rest of the validation when all the input boxes are full.

Answer (score 0):

I think the function check(this) is defined inside another function validateForm(), hence not defined.

All the functions should be defined independently,its  simple bracket issue.

Copy the below code and try:-

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">

/*
THINGS TO LOOK AT:
- ERROR TRAPPING OF CONFIRM
*/

function validateForm() {
var result = true;
var msg="";

document.getElementById('name').style.color="black";
document.getElementById('subject').style.color="black";
document.getElementById('CadNumber').style.color="black";

} //validateForm() ends here

function nameChecks() {
if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="") {
msg+=("You must enter your name \n");
document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
result = false;
}

if (!isNaN(parseInt(document.ExamEntry.name.value))) {
alert("You must only enter letters in the name! \n");
document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
result = false;
}

} //nameChecks() ends here

function subjectChecks() {
if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="") {
msg+=("You must enter the subject \n");
document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
result = false;
}

if (!isNaN(parseInt(document.ExamEntry.subject.value))) {
alert("Please make sure you only have letters in the subject! \n");
document.ExamEntry.CadNumber.focus();
document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
result = false;
}

} //subjectChecks() ends here.

function CadNumberChecks() {
if (document.ExamEntry.CadNumber.value=="") {
msg+=("You must enter the Candinate Number! \n");
document.ExamEntry.CadNumber.focus();
document.getElementById('CadNumber').style.color="red";
result = false;
} 

if (document.ExamEntry.CadNumber.value.length!== 4) {
alert("Make sure you only have 4 numbers in the Candinate Number! \n");
document.ExamEntry.CadNumber.focus();
document.getElementById('CadNumber').style.color="red";
result = false;
}

if (isNaN(parseInt(document.ExamEntry.CadNumber.value))) {
alert("Please make sure you only have numbers in the Candinate Number! \n");
document.ExamEntry.CadNumber.focus();
document.getElementById('CadNumber').style.color="red";
result = false;
}

} // CadNumberChecks ends here



function check() {
var checked = null;
var inputs = document.getElementsByName('examGroup');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
if (inputs[i].checked) {
checked = inputs[i];
break;
    }
  } // For loop ends here.

    if(checked==null){
    alert('Please choose an option.');
    return false;
    } 
    else
    return confirm('You have chosen '+ checked.value + ', is this correct?');


    nameChecks();
    subjectChecks();
    CadNumberChecks();

if (msg!="") {

}

alert(msg);

return result;
}

</script>
</head>
```